# loading web.config rewrites from all files in a folder

Tags: iis-7, url-rewriting, web-config

You may load a file that holds the rewrite rules like so.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
      <rewrite>
        <rules configSource="rewrites\site1.config" />  
      </rewrite>
      <httpErrors errorMode="Detailed" />
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

and in the folder /rewrites it finds that file site1.config which contains (for example)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<rules>

  <rule name="default_store">
    <match url="(.*)" ignoreCase="true" />
    <conditions>
      <add input="{SERVER_NAME}" pattern="^devstore\.domain\.edu*" />
    </conditions>
    <serverVariables>
      <set name="HTTP_X_MAGE_RUN_CODE" value="base" replace="true" />
      <set name="HTTP_X_MAGE_RUN_TYPE" value="website" replace="true" />
    </serverVariables>
    <action type="None" />
  </rule>


  <rule name="student_store">
    <match url="(.*)" ignoreCase="true" />
    <conditions>
      <add input="{SERVER_NAME}" pattern="^studentstore\.domain\.edu*" />
    </conditions>
    <serverVariables>
      <set name="HTTP_X_MAGE_RUN_CODE" value="studentstore" />
      <set name="HTTP_X_MAGE_RUN_TYPE" value="website" />
    </serverVariables>
    <action type="None" />
  </rule>

  <rule name="test_store">
    <match url="(.*)" ignoreCase="true" />
    <conditions>
      <add input="{SERVER_NAME}" pattern="^teststore\.domain\.edu*" />
    </conditions>
    <serverVariables>
      <set name="HTTP_X_MAGE_RUN_CODE" value="teststore" />
      <set name="HTTP_X_MAGE_RUN_TYPE" value="website" />
    </serverVariables>
    <action type="None" />
  </rule>

  <rule name="general_rewrite">
    <match url="(.*)" />
    <action type="Rewrite" url="index.php" />
    <conditions>
        <add input="{URL}" pattern="^/(media|skin|js)/" ignoreCase="false" negate="true" /> 
        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
    </conditions>
  </rule>
</rules>
```

What I would like to do here, since I want to automate the process of site creation, is to have a file for each was the thought.  so I'd have for example

1. rewrites\site1.config
2. rewrites\teststore.config
3. rewrites\devstore.config

and that I could just pick up the files.  I did try this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
      <rewrite>
        <rules configSource="rewrites\*.config" />  
      </rewrite>
      <httpErrors errorMode="Detailed" />
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

but it didn't work.  I tried to escape the * as \* just incase there was some issue with the wildcard * .  That made no change to.  So the question is how to get those files with out hard coding the path for them/

There is a secondary question here as well, that I believe I know the answer to. Is there any reason that it'd be bad to load approximately 10-30 config files from a rewrite folder.  I believe the answer is, only on the first refresh of the web.config being stored in memory.  In other words the first user is the one that pays the price for loading some many files.  This is the assumption to the main question, but is it right?

Cheers - Jeremy